# Optimize extraction of json data via OPENJSON

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, json, sql-server-2019, cross-apply

I'm attempting to optimize extraction of values obtained from a REST API which returns json values in an array.

Here's an minimal, complete, and verifiable example that reflects exactly what I'm doing.

```
USE tempdb;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.json_test;

CREATE TABLE dbo.json_test
(
    json_test_id                int                 NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , some_uniqueidentifier     uniqueidentifier    NULL
    , some_varchar              varchar(100)        NULL
    , the_json                  nvarchar(max)       NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.json_test (some_uniqueidentifier, some_varchar, the_json)
SELECT 
        some_uniqueidentifier       = NEWID()
      , some_varchar                = CONVERT(varchar(100), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(64), 1)
      , the_json = (
            SELECT st.* 
            FROM sys.tables st
                CROSS JOIN sys.tables st2
            WHERE st.object_id = t.object_id FOR JSON AUTO
            )
FROM sys.tables t;

;WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT jt.some_uniqueidentifier
        , jt.some_varchar
        , top_array.[key]
        , top_array.[value]
    FROM dbo.json_test jt
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jt.the_json, N'lax $') top_array
),
src2 AS
(
    SELECT src.some_uniqueidentifier
        , src.some_varchar
        , src.[key]
        , src.[value]
        , inner_key = inner_array.[key]
        , inner_value = inner_array.[value]
    FROM src
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(src.[value], N'lax $') inner_array
)
SELECT src2.some_uniqueidentifier
    , src2.some_varchar
    , src2.[key]
    , [name]                                = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'name'                               THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [object_id]                           = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'object_id'                          THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [principal_id]                        = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'principal_id'                       THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [schema_id]                           = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'schema_id'                          THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [parent_object_id]                    = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'parent_object_id'                   THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [type]                                = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'type'                               THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [type_desc]                           = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'type_desc'                          THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [create_date]                         = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'create_date'                        THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [modify_date]                         = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'modify_date'                        THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_ms_shipped]                       = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_ms_shipped'                      THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_published]                        = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_published'                       THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_schema_published]                 = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_schema_published'                THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [lob_data_space_id]                   = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'lob_data_space_id'                  THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [filestream_data_space_id]            = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'filestream_data_space_id'           THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [max_column_id_used]                  = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'max_column_id_used'                 THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [lock_on_bulk_load]                   = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'lock_on_bulk_load'                  THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [uses_ansi_nulls]                     = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'uses_ansi_nulls'                    THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_replicated]                       = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_replicated'                      THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [has_replication_filter]              = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'has_replication_filter'             THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_merge_published]                  = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_merge_published'                 THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_sync_tran_subscribed]             = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_sync_tran_subscribed'            THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [has_unchecked_assembly_data]         = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'has_unchecked_assembly_data'        THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [text_in_row_limit]                   = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'text_in_row_limit'                  THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [large_value_types_out_of_row]        = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'large_value_types_out_of_row'       THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_tracked_by_cdc]                   = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_tracked_by_cdc'                  THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [lock_escalation]                     = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'lock_escalation'                    THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [lock_escalation_desc]                = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'lock_escalation_desc'               THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_filetable]                        = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_filetable'                       THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_memory_optimized]                 = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_memory_optimized'                THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [durability]                          = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'durability'                         THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [durability_desc]                     = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'durability_desc'                    THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [temporal_type]                       = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'temporal_type'                      THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [temporal_type_desc]                  = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'temporal_type_desc'                 THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [history_table_id]                    = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'history_table_id'                   THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_remote_data_archive_enabled]      = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_remote_data_archive_enabled'     THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_external]                         = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_external'                        THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [history_retention_period]            = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'history_retention_period'           THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [history_retention_period_unit]       = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'history_retention_period_unit'      THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [history_retention_period_unit_desc]  = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'history_retention_period_unit_desc' THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_node]                             = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_node'                            THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
    , [is_edge]                             = MAX(CASE WHEN src2.[inner_key] = 'is_edge'                            THEN src2.[inner_value] ELSE NULL END)
FROM src2
GROUP BY src2.some_uniqueidentifier
    , src2.some_varchar
    , src2.[key]
ORDER BY src2.some_uniqueidentifier
    , src2.some_varchar
    , src2.[key];
```

The [query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Skcotv1AO) uses a couple of nested loops joins regardless of how many rows are contained in the input table.  Presumably that's an artifact of using the `CROSS APPLY` operator.  For your fun, I've already set up a [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=a548cf359ff55fa77a16677cc05050d6).

Is there a more efficient way of getting the data out of json format into a "real" set of columns?

I created the code above using my on-prem SQL Server 2019 instance, however the target will be Azure SQL Database, so all the latest-and-greatest options are available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should directly extract the values from the json array using the `WITH` clause, like this:

```
SELECT src.*
    , tt.*
FROM json_test src
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(src.the_json , 'lax $')
    WITH (
          [name]                               sysname       '$.name'
        , [object_id]                          int           '$.object_id'
        , [principal_id]                       int           '$.principal_id'
        , [schema_id]                          smallint      '$.schema_id'
        , [parent_object_id]                   int           '$.parent_object_id'
        , [type]                               char(2)       '$.type'
        , [type_desc]                          nvarchar(60)  '$.type_desc'
        , [create_date]                        datetime      '$.create_date'
        , [modify_date]                        datetime      '$.modify_date'
        , [is_ms_shipped]                      bit           '$.is_ms_shipped'
        , [is_published]                       bit           '$.is_published'
        , [is_schema_published]                bit           '$.is_schema_published'
        , [lob_data_space_id]                  int           '$.lob_data_space_id'
        , [filestream_data_space_id]           int           '$.filestream_data_space_id'
        , [max_column_id_used]                 int           '$.max_column_id_used'
        , [lock_on_bulk_load]                  bit           '$.lock_on_bulk_load'
        , [uses_ansi_nulls]                    bit           '$.uses_ansi_nulls'
        , [is_replicated]                      bit           '$.is_replicated'
        , [has_replication_filter]             bit           '$.has_replication_filter'
        , [is_merge_published]                 bit           '$.is_merge_published'
        , [is_sync_tran_subscribed]            bit           '$.is_sync_tran_subscribed'
        , [has_unchecked_assembly_data]        bit           '$.has_unchecked_assembly_data'
        , [text_in_row_limit]                  int           '$.text_in_row_limit'
        , [large_value_types_out_of_row]       bit           '$.large_value_types_out_of_row'
        , [is_tracked_by_cdc]                  bit           '$.is_tracked_by_cdc'
        , [lock_escalation]                    tinyint       '$.lock_escalation'
        , [lock_escalation_desc]               nvarchar(60)  '$.lock_escalation_desc'
        , [is_filetable]                       bit           '$.is_filetable'
        , [is_memory_optimized]                bit           '$.is_memory_optimized'
        , [durability]                         tinyint       '$.durability'
        , [durability_desc]                    nvarchar(60)  '$.durability_desc'
        , [temporal_type]                      tinyint       '$.temporal_type'
        , [temporal_type_desc]                 nvarchar(60)  '$.temporal_type_desc'
        , [history_table_id]                   int           '$.history_table_id'
        , [is_remote_data_archive_enabled]     bit           '$.is_remote_data_archive_enabled'
        , [is_external]                        bit           '$.is_external'
        , [history_retention_period]           int           '$.history_retention_period'
        , [history_retention_period_unit]      int           '$.history_retention_period_unit'
        , [history_retention_period_unit_desc] nvarchar(10)  '$.history_retention_period_unit_desc'
        , [is_node]                            bit           '$.is_node'
        , [is_edge]                            bit           '$.is_edge'
    ) AS tt
```

[This Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=32daf6b134a0e167e7bf8a2b62dd369f) compares the output from both methods proving the results are the same.

The only column missing from the output is the `key` value generated by the `OPENJSON` table-valued-function which is only returned when there is no `WITH` clause specified.  The plan for my variant only has a single nested loop, and appears to be far more efficient.

[image]

[Microsoft Docs example for OPENJSON CROSS APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#example-4---combine-relational-rows-and-json-elements-with-cross-apply)

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this recently and it is a way of speeding up access to json with index like speeds:

https://bertwagner.com/posts/one-sql-cheat-code-for-amazingly-fast-json-queries/

Not sure if this is allowed but I'll copy and paste some of the blog here:

> Recently I've been working with JSON in SQL Server 2016 a lot .
>
> One of the hesitations many people have with using JSON in SQL Server
> is that they think that querying it must be really slow — SQL is
> supposed to excel at relational data, not string parsing right?
>
> It turns out that performance is pretty good with the standalone SQL
> Server JSON functions. Even better is that it's possible to make
> queries against JSON data run at ludicrous speeds by using indexes on
> JSON parsed computed columns . In this post I want to take a look at
> how SQL is able to parse* with such great performance.
>
> *"Parse" here is actually a lie —it's doing something else behind the scenes. You'll see what I mean, keep reading!